# ASP.NET Login issues - Windows 8.1, IE 11

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-membership

I'm using .NET version 4.5.1 as I have recently upgraded after reading about similar issues from examples like this...

[ASP.NET website issues with Windows 8.1/IE 11 browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526328/asp-net-website-issues-with-windows-8-1-ie-11-browser)

Our users are having issues logging into the site using Windows 8.1 and Internet Explorer 11, the login control uses the following code but they can never log in (it just redirects them back to the login page).

```
If Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password) Then    
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName, True)
End If
```

I have also set up my web.config file as below but this issue is still stopping people logging into our website.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" name="OCBSAuth1" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="432000" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" domain="onlinecarbooty.com" />
</authentication>
```

I don't know what else to check but most users on IE11/Win 8.1 are not able to login at all.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Installing .Net framework 4.5.1 hasn't work for me. To fix it just create a new folder in your project call it `App_Browsers` and in the folder create a new file and call it `ie.browser`. In the file add this code.

```
<browsers>
  <browser id="IE11" parentID="Mozilla">
    <identification>
      <userAgent match="Trident\/7.0; rv:(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(\.(?'minor'\d+)?)(?'letters'\w*))(?'extra'[^)]*)" />
      <userAgent nonMatch="IEMobile" />
    </identification>
    <capture>
      <userAgent match="Trident/(?'layoutVersion'\d+)" />
    </capture>
    <capabilities>
      <capability name="browser"              value="IE" />
      <capability name="layoutEngine"         value="Trident" />
      <capability name="layoutEngineVersion"  value="${layoutVersion}" />
      <capability name="extra"                value="${extra}" />
      <capability name="isColor"              value="true" />
      <capability name="letters"              value="${letters}" />
      <capability name="majorversion"         value="${major}" />
      <capability name="minorversion"         value="${minor}" />
      <capability name="screenBitDepth"       value="8" />
      <capability name="type"                 value="IE${major}" />
      <capability name="version"              value="${version}" />
    </capabilities>
  </browser>

  <!-- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11,0) like Gecko -->
  <browser id="IE110" parentID="IE11">
    <identification>
      <capability name="majorversion" match="11" />
    </identification>

    <capabilities>
      <capability name="ecmascriptversion"    value="3.0" />
      <capability name="jscriptversion"       value="5.6" />
      <capability name="javascript"           value="true" />
      <capability name="javascriptversion"    value="1.5" />
      <capability name="msdomversion"         value="${majorversion}.${minorversion}" />
      <capability name="w3cdomversion"        value="1.0" />
      <capability name="ExchangeOmaSupported" value="true" />
      <capability name="activexcontrols"      value="true" />
      <capability name="backgroundsounds"     value="true" />
      <capability name="cookies"              value="true" />
      <capability name="frames"               value="true" />
      <capability name="javaapplets"          value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsCallback"     value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsFileUpload"   value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsVCard"        value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsXmlHttp"      value="true" />
      <capability name="tables"               value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsAccessKeyAttribute"    value="true" />
      <capability name="tagwriter"            value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
      <capability name="vbscript"             value="true" />
    </capabilities>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

Comment: I had done that previously before I upgraded to 4.5.1 but will try it again and see if it makes any difference thanks

Comment: This is still occurring so I'm completely at a loss as to what it could be?

Comment: Make sure you have .Net 4.5.1 framework installed on the sever, else the code above will only works for windows 7 with IE 11. For Windows 8.1 the latest.Net 4.5.1 framework is required.

Comment: Hi there, that is exactly what I've done.  When I first read about this problem we were running Version 3.5 so I've had the server upgraded and are now running 4.5.1 but it hasn't made any difference.  I have also added the browser file above but Windows 8.1/IE11 users are still having problems with not being able to log in at all

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact behaviour during login,
(it just redirects back to the login page).

I fixed it with @informatiker's answer, thought I would post this so
people with similar issue can at least try that fix

p.s. When I made right click on App_Browsers, Add >, it offered Browser File
so I guess it recognized it as file type this might be crucial to make it work right

~ good luck